# C# RegEx - find html tags (div and anchor)

Tags: c#, html, regex, find, tags

I have to retrieve several div section (of specific class name "row ") with it's content, and additionally find all anchor tags (link urls) (with class "underline red bold").
Shortly speaing : get section of:

```
<div class = "row ">
 ... (divs, tags ...)
<a class="underline red bold" href="/searchClickThru?pid=prod56534895&amp;q=&amp;rpos=109181&amp;rpp=10&amp;_dyncharset=UTF-8&amp;sort=&amp;url=/culture-and-gender-intimate-relation-ksiazka,prod56534895,p">
```

and 
collections of urls

```
string[] urls = {"/searchClickThru?pid=prod56534895&amp;q=&amp;rpos=109181&amp;rpp=10&amp;_dyncharset=UTF-8&amp;sort=&amp;url=/culture-and-gender-intimate-relation-ksiazka,prod56534895,p"}
```

the entire page looks like that:

```
<html>
```

... a lot of stuff

```
<div class="row ">

  <div class="photo">
    <a rel="nofollow" href="/searchClickThru?pid=prod56534895&amp;q=&amp;rpos=109181&amp;rpp=10&amp;_dyncharset=UTF-8&amp;sort=&amp;url=/culture-and-gender-intimate-relation-ksiazka,prod56534895,p">
      <img alt="alt msg" src="/b/s/b9/03/b9038292d147a582add07ee1f0607827.jpg">                 
 </a>
  </div>

  <div class="desc">
    <div class="l1">
      <div class="icons">
      </div>

      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="fleft">
                <a class="underline red bold" href="/searchClickThru?pid=prod56534895&amp;q=&amp;rpos=109181&amp;rpp=10&amp;_dyncharset=UTF-8&amp;sort=&amp;url=/culture-and-gender-intimate-relation-ksiazka,prod56534895,p">
                  Culture And Gender   <br>Intimate Relation</a>
              </div>

              <div class="fleft">

              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="l2">

      <div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="but">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="l3">
      Long description
      <a class="underlinepix_red no_wrap" rel="nofollow" href="/searchClickThru?pid=prod56534895&amp;q=&amp;rpos=109181&amp;rpp=10&amp;_dyncharset=UTF-8&amp;sort=&amp;url=/culture-and-gender-intimate-relation-ksiazka,prod56534895,p">
        more<img alt="" src="/b/img/arr_red_sm.gif">
  </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="omit"></div>

<div class="row ">

  <div class="photo">
    <a rel="nofollow" href="/searchClickThru?pid=prod56534895&amp;q=&amp;rpos=109181&amp;rpp=10&amp;_dyncharset=UTF-8&amp;sort=&amp;url=/culture-and-gender-intimate-relation-ksiazka,prod56534899,p">
      <img alt="alt msg" src="/b/s/b9/03/b9038292d147a582add07ee1f06078222.jpg">                    
 </a>
  </div>

  <div class="desc">
    <div class="l1">
      <div class="icons">
      </div>

      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="fleft">
                <a class="underline red bold" href="/searchClickThru?pid=prod56534895&amp;q=&amp;rpos=109181&amp;rpp=10&amp;_dyncharset=UTF-8&amp;sort=&amp;url=/culture-and-gender-intimate-relation-ksiazka,prod5653489225,p">
                  Culture And Gender   <br>Intimate Relation</a>
              </div>

              <div class="fleft">

              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="l2">

      <div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="but">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="l3">
      Long description
      <a class="underlinepix_red no_wrap" rel="nofollow" href="/searchClickThru?pid=prod56534895&amp;q=&amp;rpos=109181&amp;rpp=10&amp;_dyncharset=UTF-8&amp;sort=&amp;url=/culture-and-gender-intimate-relation-ksiazka,prod56534895,p">
        more<img alt="" src="/b/img/arr_red_sm.gif">
  </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me to create suitable reg ex?

Comment: this post says regex and html in the same sentence :D brace yourself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 15):

Regular expressions are not well suited for this.

Due to the nested nature of HTML, a regular expression that does what you ask would be very (very very) long and complicated. Use a HTML Parser instead.

Comment: +1 and by 'a HTML Parser', Jens means HTML Agility Pack and nothing else, ever, for any C# html parsing needs: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/Wikipage

Comment: Obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: It is a little sad that this is my highest voted answer so far.. =)

Comment: Take your victories where you can get them, my friend... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is roughly the same as the answer to this question:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you've managed to get into LINQ and like the power of LINQ, there appears to be a [LINQ-to-HTML Library](http://www.justagile.com/linq-to-html.aspx) available for download. I haven't tried it yet, so I cannot speak to its ability.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/Wikipage)

> This is an agile HTML parser that
>   builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually
>   don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is
>   a .NET code library that allows you to
>   parse "out of the web" HTML files. The
>   parser is very tolerant with "real
>   world" malformed HTML. The object
>   model is very similar to what proposes
>   System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or
>   streams).

Answer (score 0):

Is it NECESSARY to use regular expressions? If not, then why don't you use an HTML parser like [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/Wikipage)... it will be MUCH easier to get what you want if you use a parser instead of regular expressions.